# Easier way to have a dark options menu on Android-14 and above?

Tags: android

My app is using the Light holo theme with DarkActionBar. I really like the sleek look. I have updated the navigation list to use getActionBar().getThemedContext() and they do appear properly with the dark background.

I want to make the menu options (for phones with menu key like Nexus S) with black background as well, just like the built in Drive app. For devices that do not have the menu key, the overflow menu does appear with the dark background.

I have searched stackoverflow and there's quite a lot of posts, but those are concerning android 2.X. Since there's a getThemedContext() on android-14 and above, is there a simpler way to make the menu options dark?